# Issues with loading a new model in the /admin console

Tags: python, mysql, django, hosting, passenger

I have the following setup:

- Domain on Dreamhost.com with Passenger enabled for WSGI
- Python 3.4
- Django 1.7 in a virtualenv
- MySQL database

I have set everything up correctly and currently learning to code in the Django environment.

I have successfully completed the first part of the Django official tutorial located here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/
and started to work on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/

This resulted in the creation of a "polls" app within "mysite" project.

The "polls" app has 2 models: Question and Choice.

Everything successfully synced with MySQL.

I then accessed the polls/admin.py and wrote the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

Which should enable the Question model within the admin interface.

When I tried to access the mydomain.com/admin interface the model Question didn't show up. According to the tutorial it should have.

I have given it some thought after doing some research, and then tried to touch the mydomain.com/tmp/restart.txt file in order to restart the `passenger_wsgi.py` file. This file is called to link the Apache server with my django app as per the [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) setup.

After that, everything worked! Why did it work? I don't understand why `passenger_wsgi.py` had to be restarted.

This is the code inside passenger_wsgi.py:

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)

project_location = cwd + "/djtest"

sys.path.insert(0,project_location)
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/home/USERNAME/Python34/lib'

#Switch to new python
PYTHON_EXE = '/home/USERNAME/DOMAIN/env/bin/python3'

if sys.executable != PYTHON_EXE:
    os.execl(PYTHON_EXE, PYTHON_EXE, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0,'home/USERNAME/DOMAIN/env/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,'home/USERNAME/DOMAIN/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,'home/USERNAME/DOMAIN/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "djtest.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how WSGI works: the Python code is loaded on process startup, and isn't refreshed on each request (unless explicitly configured to do so.)

While following the tutorial - and indeed throughout development - you'd be better off developing locally and using the built-in development server via `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: thank you for your answer! That makes a lot of sense. I thought initially that only the code within passenger_wsgi file is loaded, and then it is used to call the actual app. So if I was to edit my app files they would instantly become available on my domain...at least that's what I thought. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Try running the dev server (manage.py runserver) and then change some code...you will see the console change when it finishes reloading the code.